# Time Complexity of "in" (containment operator)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, time-complexity

I was just wondering when understanding the time complexity of an algorithm like the one below.

For a python list, if we have a for loop iterating over it, and then a containment check, would the time complexity of that be O(n^2).

I know both are O(n) (or I think) so having them nested in one another would that make it O(n^2)?

I think if this "list" is actually a list, then the time complexity of the code below is O(n^2). But if it's a dictionary it would be O(n) because lookup is O(1). Is that correct?

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
for element in list:
    if x in list:
```

Comment: A few comments on your example: First (and least relevant to real code, I suspect), don't use `list` as a variable name, as you'll shadow the builtin type. Next (and *maybe* more relevant), you don't need to test if the list you're iterating over and the one you're checking membership in are the same. The `in` test will always be true, so there's no need for it. If they're separate lists (or dictionaries) then `O(n^2)` may not be correct because it assumed *both* lists are of size `n`. If they could have different sizes, you should describe the run time as `O(m*n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

- List containment is O(n), and doing an O(n) operation O(n) times is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- Dictionary lookups are O(1), and doing an O(1) operation O(n) times is O(n).

Comment: @Mateus Please explain how this does not answer the question.